# Using Java8 to filter with multiple attributes only if they are not null

Tags: java-8

I have an object like so

```
public class Organization {

  private List<Employee> employees;

  public static class Employee {
    private String department;
    private String designation;
  }
}
```

I have a search method that takes in a `Map<String, Object>`. This map can contain either the key-value for department or designation or both.

```
{department -> "cs"} or
{designation -> "engineer"} or
{department -> "cs", designation -> "engineer"}
```

Here's what I need to do. If the department key exists, I need to return all employees for that dept. If department AND designation keys exist, I need to return all employees that match both the criteria. How do I do this?

How do I filter employees given the map is dynamic?

Comment: From what you say looks like department is always present. Its only designation that is optionally present?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is probably to run multiple filters:

```
Stream<Employee> employeeStream = employees.stream();
if (filter.get("department") != null)
    employeeStream = employeeStream.filter(e -> filter.get("department").equals(e.getDepartment()));
if (filter.get("designation") != null)
    employeeStream = employeeStream.filter(e -> filter.get("designation").equals(e.getDesignation()));
List<Employee> result = employeeStream.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The other way is to use single filter and check the existence of the key in the filtering lambda:

```
List<Employee> result = employees.stream()
    .filter((Employee e) -> {
         return
             (filter.get("department") == null || filter.get("department").equals(e.getDepartment())) &&
             (filter.get("designation") == null || filter.get("designation").equals(e.getDesignation()));
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

EDIT: As discussed in comments, consider storing result of filter.get() into temporary variable and use directly in the filtering lambda.

Comment: The program logic is ok, but you should avoid the redundant `get` calls…

Comment: @Holger : You're right it would be worth. I wanted to avoid spreading the code too much with defining new variables so the conceptual part is still straightforward and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather go for an or-condition in the filter:

```
employees.stream()
    .filter(e -> !filter.containsKey("department") || filter.get("department").equals(e.getDepartment()))
    .filter(e -> !filter.containsKey("designation") || filter.get("designation").equals(e.getDesignation()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```